# how to get public key from X509Store using PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true)

Tags: c#, web-services, rsa, sha256

I'm new to this, I'm creating a webservice for our client that requires sign data using private key with an algorithm of SHA256withRSA in header. How can I produce public key using X509Certificate2's PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true) property?

I've tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.publickey.encodedkeyvalue?view=netframework-4.8

```
string certSubject = "CN=cnName";
            X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in my.Certificates)
            {
                if (x509.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
                {
                    RSACryptoServiceProvider publicCertifiedRSACryptoServiceProvider = x509.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

                    string publickeyRAW = x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

I'm expecting a string or byte for my final output, but this is what I'm getting:

```
30 82 01 0a 02 82 01 01 00 9c 71 98 bc de 99 0b f7 b7 0a bf 79 f7 02 2a 0c c1 a0 45 10 6b 5c a0 d7 e5 02 1e 01 f9 3c d7 69 4e 7c ec ee 56 cf c2 88 74 fd bb fe 97 77 07 6b f7 85 ee 8d e6 1b 2f 8e 90 03 6e 4a f8 42 9e 10 e9 7d f7 1b bd dc ba 2b 38 8e 7b 5a c9 67 2e 87 a7 87 54 98 16 7a 67 aa c7 d7 6c f5 50 4c e6 7d 79 8c 46 f4 c6 39 57 b4 75 ef 8d d5 8d 3a 33 aa 5e b9 c3 48 6f eb 04 fe b0 86 b8 28 20 f3 57 44 1b 57 6f fd ce c0 15 f0 ff cf 73 72 a4 76 55 84 e9 c9 54 f1 3a fe 29 c0 be d4 0d 38 1c 73 1e 41 a5 d2 a5 f7 4c 9f 72 49 ba 28 5d a4 bf db cd 05 68 aa f8 62 66 e0 70 65 35 9f 56 64 48 f7 1b df d1 0e f6 2f e7 36 16 5b 1c ff d5 5a a5 97 63 de 8c 36 da 2c 9d 13 d2 72 09 c1 b6 48 de 8c 67 c1 64 2e 1d 39 cf cd 0c 88 67 3c e3 3c 17 eb 23 fe d2 47 6f 51 20 28 88 7e a7 22 b8 a8 a7 43 d4 5d 02 03 01 00 01
```

How can I decrypt or convert this to string?

Comment: It’s a hex string of the RSAPublicKey value (representing your 2048 bit modulus and your standard exponent). What kind of thing are you hoping for?

Comment: @bartonjs, a function that will convert it to string, or other way to convert it to string.

Comment: But it /is/ a string... obviously you’re expecting some format other than hexadecimal bytes.

Comment: @bartonjs, something like this: MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtKx+XhLVjFjH/rv8SVGV6EZmqZBdbKEWxv/jWMr9hHxw/TSP6E5YRjf96W9mPBxu12PMGLSLeaAIHVo42untJvZ55wIdWy7yRLdXns/jzScEcK+kBGAfglqyKcWQZhwdTOVT7EsBUHq2T1x59M1u5gA4XOogFHPm8fpkL9cYblrgcoM1GkfwF0RdCXkQsLdbfJ2ObpWgkTdneTzej9IOZVWvavecQuk+lSJPysOIscqZa7UXChGb6GC3ByH4Vy6QdAqn3ONSUmTtX+z/xX2QY/sFHRbfxDVcmzbGHI8wyCBNrzKpMK57Ok9RP7cK3IFaS8xRien00oRgKm2tGxQMsQIDAQAB

I need to convert that hexa to a public key string like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your desired outcome you probably want

```
Convert.ToBase64String(x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.RawData);
```

Comment: Client gave sample public key:
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtKx+XhLVjFjH/rv8SVGV6EZmqZBdbKEWxv/jWMr9hHxw/TSP6E5YRjf96W9mPBxu12PMGLSLeaAIHVo42untJvZ55wIdWy7yRLdXns/jzScEcK+kBGAfglqyKcWQZhwdTOVT7EsBUHq2T1x59M1u5gA4XOogFHPm8fpkL9cYblrgcoM1GkfwF0RdCXkQsLdbfJ2ObpWgkTdneTzej9IOZVWvavecQuk+lSJPysOIscqZa7UXChGb6GC3ByH4Vy6QdAqn3ONSUmTtX+z/xX2QY/sFHRbfxDVcmzbGHI8wyCBNrzKpMK57Ok9RP7cK3IFaS8xRien00oRgKm2tGxQMsQIDAQAB

But it seems EncodedKeyValue.RawData doesnt return a lenght like that.